# What does this attribute below mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen this example on the web:

```
$('#questionTextArea').each( function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var $questionText = $("<textarea class='textAreaQuestion'></textarea>")
                   .attr('name',$this.attr('name'))
                   .attr('value',$this.val());

    $question.append($questionText);

    });
```

Where it says '.attr('name',$this.attr('name'))', what does that mean? Does that give the same 'name' attribute as the 'id' attribute #questionTextArea or the same 'name' as the 'class' attribute 'textAreaQuestion'?

Thanks

Comment: As you're using $this, I'd say questionTextArea

Comment: so the id and and the name attribute both equal 'questionTextArea'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is assigning the `name` attribute on each newly created `<textarea>` to the `name` attribute of `#questionTextArea`.

```
// Points $this to the current node the .each() is iterating on (#questionTextArea)
var $this = $(this);

// The name attribute of the current node .each() is iterating on
$this.attr('name');
```

Note that since it's an id queried, there should only be one of these, and therefore the `.each()` loop is kind of unnecessary.
The same thing could be accomplished with something like:

```
var $questionText = $("<textarea class='textAreaQuestion'></textarea>")
   .attr('name', $('#questionTextArea').attr('name'))
   .attr('value', $('#questionTextArea').val());
```

Comment: So can I ask what this name attribute actually equals to? in other words 'name=...'

Comment: @user1304948 We don't know from the posted code what the actual value of `name` is. Whatever the `name='something'` on the element with `id='questionTextArea'` (assume that's a `<textarea>`) is what the newly created on is being set to `name='something'`